# ribbon call back method implementaion in VSTO for outlook addin

Tags: visual-c++, callback, outlook, ribbon, outlook-addin

i have to implement onbutton click activity in ribbon callback and i have this xml.

```
<button id="GoToAppConfiguration" size="large" label="Application Configuration" imageMso="AutoArchiveSettings" onAction="OnActionCallback"/>
```

and i am using function like this in ribbon call back :

```
public void OnActionCallback(Office.IRibbonControl control, bool isPressed)
    {
        if (control.Id == "GoToAppConfiguration")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You clicked " + control.Id);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You clicked a different control.");
        }
    }
```

but above code is not working ..

i think control is not going to that function it self..

please help ..

## nikhil

Comment: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942866.aspx)

Comment: code help taken from here [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942866.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your callback method signature doesn't match [what the Ribbon XML is looking for](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523%28v=office.12%29.aspx). You need to omit the second parameter `isPressed`.

```cs
public void OnActionCallback(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
    if (control.Id == "GoToAppConfiguration")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You clicked " + control.Id);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You clicked a different control.");
    }
}
```

Comment: thnks for reply .. it worked out ..but when do we pass second parameter it is not clear can u help SliverNinja

Comment: @zytham - to answer this "when to use other parameters" question, refer to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691833.aspx#odc_Office2010Introduction2OutSpaceUI_DescriptionsAttributesChildInformation)